# How can I resolve seams in normal map?

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking, normal-map, seams

[image]

How you can see, i've already baked the normal map with the image in *Non-Color*, so it isn't the problem. I thought it might be the uvs, the shirt has a seam down the middle, but I'm not sure. What could it be?

Comment: Hello, could you please pack your images (File > External Data > Pack Resources) and share your file?

Comment: The normal map displayed in the image editor does not look like the right color for a tangent space normal map.  I believe that the problem has to do with how you baked this (or perhaps, some kind of post-processing you did on the normal map image that isn't described.)  I can't recommend using a normal map strength greater than 1.0 either.

Comment: moon boots, hello! Sorry for the delay, actually I already deleted the files, but even so they were common images created from blender, (as it would be done conventionally). However, the one for the normal map was set to a "non-color" color space in the settings; when preparing it before baking, the UV coordinates (if you see the character's shirt), are cut in half, (that is, the front and back of the shirt are organized, cut), and as you see in the render in evee in blender, the normal map is shown baked in the uvs coordinates organized like this ugly, with a light side and a dark side